# Validate filename using PHP ("a-z", "0-9" and "-")

Tags: php, file-upload, filenames, validation

What is the best way to validate a filename using PHP and how can I do it?

I want to see if filename contains only "a-z", "0-9" and "-". Also make sure the filename has no capital letters.

```
$file = 'the-name.ext';

if ($file == 'only contains a-z, 0-9 or "-"' // HOW TO
&& $file == 'lowercasse'  // HOW TO
&& $file == 'a-z')  // HOW TO
{
    // upload code here
}
else{
    echo 'The file "' . $file . '"was not uploaded. The file can only contain "a-z", "0-9" and "-". Allso the files must be lowercasse. ';
}
```

I ended up doing something like this, to get rid of the file extension:

```
$filename = 'fil-name.jpg';
$filname_without_ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/',$filname_without_ext)) {
   echo'$file is valid';
} else {
   echo'$file is not valid';
}
```

Comment: On a side matter: your `else` message is misleading, as it seems to refer to file content, not names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+\.ext$/', $file)) {
    // .. upload
} else {
    echo 'The file "' . $file . '"was not uploaded. The file can only contain "a-z", "0-9" and "-". Allso the files must be lowercase. ';

}
```

Change `ext` with your required extension. Or better yet, strip it with [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), and use [`finfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) to ensure the file is of the correct type.

Comment: THANKS Michael, that's why i didn't got it to work. I forgot the file extension...

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/',$file)) {
   // $file is valid
} else {
   // $file is not valid
}
```

Comment: does not work with an extension. example: example.ext

Answer (score 1):

Simply using regex will do the work for you

```
([a-z0-9-]+)
```

This pattern will match a-z, 0-9 and -

Comment: This ignores any file extension

Comment: Why are underscores not allowed?

Comment: @bart I do not know, it was asked in this question to only validate what my regex validates. If you also want to include underscores, it would be `([a-z0-9-_]+)`